# Open source self hostable documentation tool needed

Tags: web-apps, document-management, multi-user, documentation

I am looking for a web based tool to host some documentation.
Something like confluence but without payments.

I already found [documize](https://github.com/documize/community) but it has issues if you want to build it by yourself and also is limited by the amount of possible users.

Requirements in detail:

1. Multi user based
2. open source
3. web based
4. file upload possible
5. nestable/foldable contents
6. inline table support
7. image upload support

What else could I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BookStack](https://www.bookstackapp.com/) may be close to what you're looking for. It supports lots of account-related features, file uploads and various WYSIWYG formatitng tools including the ones you listed. And the UI is somewhere between a documentation and a wiki, but of course can be adapted.